# Windows 2008 Terminal Service: per-user timeout configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services

I have a windows 2008 box running terminal services and i used group policy to setup a timeout of 10 minutes for idle sessions which works great for all users.

The issue is that i have 3 users which i need to override the timeout with a bigger value.

Microsoft KB ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758177%28WS.10%29.aspx ) mentions something in the Notes part but i just can't find it.

Any ideas of how do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that means is that the policy can be set per computer and will affect everyone logging on to that server or it can be set per user and will affect every user to which that particular GPO applies. What you'll need to do is to create 2 GPO's for that setting: 1 for the 10 minute timeout and 1 for the longer timeout, configure the setting under User Configuration, and use Security Filtering to apply the GPO to the relevant users/groups.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even after assigning an user to a group policy without timeouts, it keeps disconnecting. Any ideas of what i should check? Anyway to know which group policy is in effect for user X?

Comment: You can run gpresults to see which policies are in effect for each user. If you have the setting set in both Computer Configuration and User Configuration then the Computer Configuration setting takes precedence. You need to check that the GPO is linked to the correct OU and that you're using the appropriate Security Filtering to make it apply to the user(s) in question.